# the slopes of the chords of continuous functions is an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

exersice from a book:

Let $f$ be continuous and defined in an interval $A$. A line segment joining two points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ in the graph $y=f(x)$, where $a$ and $b$ are distinct points in $A$, is called a chord. As is usual in analytic geometry the slope of the chord is the number
$$
p:=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}
$$
Let $B$ be the set of all numbers $p$, such that there exists a chord with slope $p$. Show that $B$ is an interval.

> Proof:
>
> Given two chords, the first whose endpoints have $x$-coordinates $a_{0}$ and $b_{0}$, and the second whose endpoints have $x$ -coordinates $a_{1}$ and $b_{1}$, consider the variable chord whose endpoints have $x$ -coordinates $a_{t}$ and $b_{t}$, where
> $$
> a_{t}=(1-t) a_{0}+t a_{1}, \quad b_{t}=(1-t) b_{0}+t b_{1}, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1.
> $$
> Then we can define a function $$
> p_t:=\frac{f(a_t)-f(b_t)}{(1-t)(a_0-b_0)+t(a_1-b_1)}.
> $$
> Meanwhile $f$ is continious then $p$ is also continious. And by previous theorems we know that image of the continious function defined in an interval is also interval.

Is this proof complete or I missing something????